# How do you add a subjectNameAlt extension to X509_REQ?

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I am creating a CSR which is going to be processed by my server. It needs to set the subjectNameAlt so that the server can process it. I've searched far and wide, and have only found how to do it with normal X509 certs, not X509_REQ. How can I do this (with C and OpenSSL. I.e. I need the equivalent of `X509_get_ext_d2i` but for `X509_REQ`)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Programmatically

Have a look at the [`demos/x509/mkreq.c`](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=demos/x509/mkreq.c;h=d1cba9dc5a6d393444f78b23101afdaf7b3436c7;hb=HEAD) file that comes with OpenSSL. It creates a request and adds an email address as an alternative name. Stripped down it does the following:

```
exts = sk_X509_EXTENSION_new_null();
add_ext(exts, NID_subject_alt_name, "email:steve@openssl.org");
X509_REQ_add_extensions(x, exts);
sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free(exts, X509_EXTENSION_free);
```

The `add_ext` is implemented like this:

```
int add_ext(STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) *sk, int nid, char *value) {
  X509_EXTENSION *ex;
  ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, nid, value);
  if (!ex)
    return 0;
  sk_X509_EXTENSION_push(sk, ex);
  return 1;
}
```

## From the command line

*I leave this section in place for others, although OP requested an API.*

https://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName advises to copy the `openssl.cnf` file to a temporary `openssl-san.cnf` file and then edit that like this:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = host1.yourdomain.tld
DNS.2 = host2.yourdomain.tld
```

Comment: I want to do this via c, not through the shell or filesystem.

Comment: Awesome! I've been looking for this for hours!

Comment: How can we add multivalue extension like in[alt_names], using c programmatically?

Comment: I found you couldn't add arbitrary data as the subject alt name. I see in your example you use "email:...". I found prepending the value I wanted to use with "DNS:" worked for me. Otherwise X509V3_EXT_conf_nid() just returned null.

Comment: The `X509V3_EXT_conf_nid` function only works with a NULL context for some extensions. Other extensions require the x509 context in order to generate their data.